# Safari Date Time Issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, clock

```js
(function() {

      var days, hours, minutes, seconds;
      setInterval(function() {
        var live_date = $('.livedate');
        var current_date = new Date().getTime();
        for (var i = 0; i < live_date.length; i++) {
          var date = live_date[i].getAttribute('data-countdown');
          var seconds_left = (new Date(date).getTime() - current_date) / 1000;
          days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
          if (seconds_left <= 0) {
            
          }
          else {
            days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
            seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;
            hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
            seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;
            minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
            seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);
            $('.livedate').html(days + "D" + " " + hours + "H" + " " + minutes);
          }

        }
      }, 1000);


})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="livedate" data-countdown='11/23/2018 23:59:00'> </div>
```

i have an issue with the date object here for some reason the clock does not display in safari can does anyone see the reason why thanks appreciate it,

Comment: I just opened this page in Safari and it appears to work fine. Are you referring to the desktop or mobile Safari version?

Answer (score 0):

1- It could be because of the way you read the attribute, `getAttribute` could be only used in Safari 6 or greater versions:

[image]

Check out: [Element.getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

if you are using the older versions of Safari you should simply use [jQuery's `.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function change this line:

```
var date = live_date[i].getAttribute('data-countdown');
```

to

```
var date = $(live_date[i]).attr('data-countdown');
```

or if you only have one element with the class name `.livedate`:

```
var date = live_date.attr('data-countdown');
```

2- ***Another possible issue*** could be that only in HTML 5 you could use custom attributes prefixed with `data-` so make sure you are actually using HTML 5.

3- ***Another possible issue*** could be the format of the date string, so to make sure you could use UTC format and change this line:

```
<div class="livedate" data-countdown='11/23/2018 23:59:00'> </div>
```

to:

```
<div class="livedate" data-countdown='2018-11-23T23:59:00'></div>
```

---

**Note:** In your code there are some rooms for improvements, like the point that for loop you have suggests that you might have more than one `.livedate` element in your page, so if that's the case it would be better to only change the inside test of the relevant `.livedate`:

```
var el = $(live_date[i]);
var date = el.attr('data-countdown');
//the rest of your code
el.html(days + "D" + " " + hours + "H" + " " + minutes);
```

The other improvement is to use [jQuery's `.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) for your loop:

```
var live_date = $('.livedate');
var current_date = new Date().getTime();
live_date.each(function(index, element){
  var el = $(element);
  var date = el.attr('data-countdown');
  //the rest of your code
  el.html(days + "D" + " " + hours + "H" + " " + minutes);
});
```

Comment: thanks , i had some other scripts conflicting issue thanks for the help